# Select changes not triggering if added by JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, forms, onchange

I have a multi level select chain, where by the value of the first select generates the options for the next select list.  And within the second list some of the values will cause a div to display with another input.

My codes (below) seem to work just fine when tested on static content (ie: the second select is hard coded in the html).  But when I add it with JQuery, the second level no longer triggers the .change function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $dts = $("select[name='tourdes']");
  $dts.change(function() { 
     var dtsValue = $(this).val();
     var dtsString = '?tourdes=' + dtsValue; 
     $('#dateSelect').show();
     $('#dateSelect').load('include/avdates.php' + dtsString).append();
  });
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $tags = $("select[name='tourcode']");
  $tags.change(function() {
     if ($(this).val() == "private") {
     $(".prvcal").css({"visibility":"visible"});
  }
  });
});
</script>
```

I am guessing something needs to be re-initialized, but I am getting no where with my experiments.

Comment: Does your code rebuild the entire `<select>` element or does it just re-do the `<option>` tags in it? If the former, then the problem is that your handler binding won't survive the re-generation of the element.

Comment: Yu should only have a single $(document).ready(function(){}}; What happens when you place both change functions inside 1 ready function?

Comment: It replacing a "loading.." text message with the <select> and some text, since different options have different instructions.

Comment: I did try combining them together to no effect.  They are currently separate simply to keep code easier to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using jQuery 1.7 you'll want to use `on`, as both `live` and `delegate` are deprecated.

```
$(document).on("change", "select[name='tourcode']", function() {
    var dtsValue = $(this).val();
    var dtsString = '?tourdes=' + dtsValue; 
    $('#dateSelect').show();
    $('#dateSelect').load('include/avdates.php' + dtsString).append();
});
```

[docs for on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  By changing both functions to using .on() I was finally able to get it all working.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using dynamically-generated HTML elements. If that is the case, you need to use `.delegate()` to handle them:

```
$('select').delegate("[name='tourdes']", 'change', function() {
```

Comment: Or, preferably, `delegate()` (jQuery <1.7) or `on()` (jQuery >= 1.7).

Comment: Or preferably ".delegate()" or ".on()" because ".live()" is really kind-of a dumb API. *edit* -- whoa @DavidThomas freaky

Comment: Am I supposed to use delegate() on the dts <select>?  The dts is for the hard coded <select> and tags is for the <select> that is added.

Comment: I have been trying as suggested but without success.  I have been using `  $('select').delegate("[name='tourcode']", 'change', function() {
 if ($(this).val() == "private") {
 $(".prvcal").css({"visibility":"visible"});
 });
  });`  but no luck.  If it is inside the document.ready function it disables the existing function, if in its own document.ready the existing function works but not the delegate function

Comment: When you call `document.ready()` twice, it *overrides* the existing `document.ready()` function. You need to merge them.

Comment: When I merge them, neither the initial dts.change nor the new .delegate work

Comment: Thanks, that cleared up the interference with the first dts function, but the delegate function still does not work.

Comment: THANKS for all your help.  I am not sure of the logic/reason but when I switched both functions to using .on() as mentioned in the 2nd answer it started working.